# query_posts clarification needed

Tags: loop, query-posts

I understand for the most what query_posts does and how it works. I also know it's not good practice to use it. But I would like to know exactly what the "$posts" variable does in this setup:

```
<?php 

global $query_string; 
$posts = query_posts($query_string.'&cat=-9'); 

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
...
endwhile; else:
...
endif;
wp_reset_query(); // reset the query
?>
```

Can someone please explain how "$posts" is used within the loop? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone please explain how "$posts" is used within the loop?

**It isn't.**

It returns the array of queried posts , but it is insignificant and not used at all: if you remove it than the code works the same:

```
global $query_string; 
query_posts($query_string.'&cat=-9'); 

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
...
endwhile; endif;
```

This is because `query_posts()` override **global** `$wp_query` object, that is the same query object that loop functions like `have_posts()` and `the_post()` use to display posts.

and this is the reason why that function should not be used:

- overriding a widely used global variable it easily has side effects
- it is very slow, because you override a already ran query with another, running query to database 2 times.

If you need a separate query from main (global) query, than make no sense override main query, just perform a secondary query using `WP_Query` object or `get_posts`.

If you need to modify main query, than modify it **before** it runs, in this way you'll run only 1 query instead of 2 and your code will be faster. To edit main query before it runs, use `'pre_get_posts'` action hook.